# Getting org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join for inner join query in java

Tags: java, spring, hql

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(" FROM Organisation org ")
                .append(" INNER JOIN Abonne a ")
                .append(" WHERE org.idOrganisation = a.organisation ");
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

I am getting path expected for the  INNER JOIN Abonne a  WHERE org.idOrganisation = a.organisation  order by org.code ]

Abonne Entity
The abonne entity has the organisation foreign key
@ Join table id_org

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_ABONNE")
    public class Abonne {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7500240243978256087L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID_ABONNE", columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
        private String idAbonne;

        @Column(name = "LIB_NOM", length = 200, nullable = false)
        private String nom;

        @Column(name = "BOO_ACTIF", nullable = false)
        private Boolean actif;

        @Column(name = "DAT_DATE_EXPIRATION", length = 10)
        @Type(type="utcType")
        private Date dateExpiration;

        @Column(name="NO_MAXIM_DE_UTILISATEURS", length = 5000)
        private Integer noMaxUsers;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_LANGUAGE", nullable=false)
        @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ABONNE_ID_LANGUAGE_IDX)
        @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
        private Language language;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_THEME", nullable=false)
        @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ABONNE_ID_THEME_IDX)
        @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
        private Theme theme;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_FONT", nullable=false)
        @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ABONNE_ID_FONT_IDX)
        private Font font;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_ORG", nullable=false, updatable=false)
        @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ABONNE_ID_ORG_IDX)
        @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
        private Organisation organisation;
}
```

Organisation Entity
This is the organisation Entity which has the idOrganisation

```
@Table(name = "T_ORGANISATION")
public class Organisation {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5348078630581306005L;

    public static final String COLUMN_ID_ORGANISATION = "ID_ORGANISATION";

    @Id
    @Column(name = COLUMN_ID_ORGANISATION, columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idOrganisation;

    @Column(name = "LIB_NOM", nullable = false, length=250)
    private String nomOrganisation;

    @Column(name = "LIB_CODE", length=100)
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FICHIER")
    @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ORGANISATION_ID_FICHIER_IDX)
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private File logo ;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query as follows:

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("select a.organisation FROM Abonne a ")
```

When you use a.organistion it will create join in hibernate on its own.
Or

Add List in organistion to have bi directional mapping and use the following query.

```
 @Table(name = "T_ORGANISATION")
    public class Organisation {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5348078630581306005L;

        public static final String COLUMN_ID_ORGANISATION = "ID_ORGANISATION";

        @Id
        @Column(name = COLUMN_ID_ORGANISATION, columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
        private String idOrganisation;

        @Column(name = "LIB_NOM", nullable = false, length=250)
        private String nomOrganisation;

        @Column(name = "LIB_CODE", length=100)
        private String code;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_FICHIER")
        @Index(name = IndexNameUtil.T_ORGANISATION_ID_FICHIER_IDX)
        @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
        private File logo ;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="organisation")
List<Abonne> abonnes;

StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(" FROM Organisation org ")
                .append(" JOIN org.abonnes a ")
                .append(" WHERE org.idOrganisation = a.organisation.idOrganisation ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:-

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(" FROM Abonne a ")
            .append(" INNER JOIN a.organisation org ")
            .append(" WHERE org.idOrganisation = a.organisation ");
```

Comment: When i changed to On still getting path expected for join: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

Comment: Please provide the definition of Organisation  and Abonne  class